# I give a pointer to a string in a function and in order to use the string I use s, not * s

Tags: c, string, pointers

I created a string in the main body and I want a function to access it. In order to access it I have to use the name of the string, not the pointer to it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(char * s,char * b){
    printf("%s\n",s);
    //printf("%s\n",*s); this crashes it
    printf("%c\n",*b);
}

int main(){
    char s[]="string";
    char b='b';
    char * pointerb=&b;
    char * pointerstring=&s;
    test(pointerstring,pointerb);
}
```

Why is line 5 correct and not line 6?

Comment: Because string formatting takes a pointer and reads memory until a null byte, whilce char will just print the value you give it

Comment: `*s` is a single character, not the pointer required for the `"%s"` format specifier. `*b` works because the `"%c"` format specifier expects a single character as the parameter.

Comment: **s** represents the address of the character array so we do not put the &. `char * pointerstring = s;`

Comment: You can read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for those format strings, and see exactly what is expected for `%s` and for `%c`. What type is `s`? What type is `*s`? Which of those matches the type expected for `%s`?

Comment: When printing a string you give printf a pointer to a string - not the actual string. Most parts of C use pointers to strings, not actual strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("%s\n",*s);
```

`%s` is a format specifier for string. it expects pointer to array of char, but you are passing argument type is `char`. this is the reason for segmentation fault.

another side note, your has warning for this line

```
char * pointerstring=&s;
```

need to change to below.

```
char * pointerstring=s;
```

char* pointerstring now points to first char of string s[] which is nothing but 's'

Here is stack visualization of how pointer point to the string when program reaches at line  `char * pointerstring=s;`

[image]